# Java.Lang.VerifyError, Jenkins bug?

Tags: java, android, jenkins

I meet a problem, which has blocked my work for three days.  :(
when I build my Android project using Ant under Jenkins, the APK can not launch in phone, and Java.Lang.VerifyError exception occurs.
The weird thing is, in the same computer, eclipse can build and create a working apk by calling Ant. The jenkins and eclipse are using the same Ant, JDK, Android SDK and proguard.
Should this be a bug of Jenkins?

I posted the the exception information generated by jenkins built apk below, could anyone give me a hand? Please let me if you need more infromation.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com.dewmobile.library.connection.network.m
at com.dewmobile.library.connection.network.s.q(Unknown Source)
at com.dewmobile.library.connection.network.s.a(Unknown Source)
at com.dewmobile.library.connection.service.DmConnectionService.e(Unknown Source)
at com.dewmobile.library.connection.service.DmConnectionService.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1966)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:997)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: bad proguard settings ? AFAIK VerifyError means that VM cant find some method in this case

Comment: I spent quite some time on progurad, but no change to proguard worked. With the same progurad sw(4.6) and progurad.cfg, on the same computer eclipse can create a "good" release apk.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.VerifyError happens when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime.

I strongly suspect there is some path issue which is picking wrong version at compile time. I would suggest revisit all your configurations one more time.

Comment: Yes, I checked the jenkins configuration once again, jenkins environment settings are nothing strange. In fact, the jenkins generated debug apk works fine, just the release apk has the problem, looks it is something to do with proguard. but eclipse can create a working release build with the same proguard.  it is really weird. I also tried to clean the jenkins workspace to clear every potential error before building release apk, but the result is the same.